# SUM of amount of each categories

Tags: php, sql, database

I tried to total up the claim amount in summary table based on type of claim.

I mean that one row for each employee but there are 3 column which is "Total vehicle claim", "total medical claim" and total others claim".

How do I do that?

EDIT (from OP's comment):

```
$query="SELECT c.empid,u.userName, SUM(c_amount) AS total vehicle claim
        FROM claim c JOIN
             user u
             ON (c.empid = u.empid)
        WHERE c_type = 'Motorcycle' OR c_type='Car'
        GROUP by empid"
```

Comment: $query="SELECT c.empid,u.userName, SUM(c_amount) AS total vehicle claim FROM claim c JOIN user u ON (c.empid = u.empid) WHERE c_type = 'Motorcycle' OR c_type='Car' GROUP by empid";

Comment: First, this is a basic aggregation query, and `group by` is a fundamental part of SQL.  So, learn a bit about SQL if you are going to use it.  Second, the question lacks important information, such as sample data, desired results, the tag of the database you are using, and code you have already tried.

Comment: this only will give me "total vehicle claim". i would like to have "total medical claim" on 2nd column.

Comment: i dont have reputation to upload the picture of my table.

Comment: @parkchu . . . Then type the table definition/contents into the query.  Text is much more useful than a picture anyway.

Comment: this is claim table.                                             INSERT INTO claim (c_id, empid, c_type, c_amount, c_date, c_desc);                                                              the table have 3 categories = vehicle, medical,others.                                                       i would like to have a table that first column would be employee name(get it from employee table where empid is fk), 2nd column is total amount of claim under "vehicle category",3rd column total amount of claim under "medical category".

Comment: sorry,i dont know to make it clear. sigh...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This can be done by creating two views. A view is a virtual table. This allows you to create a virtual table with the `empid` and the `SUM(c_amount)` for vehicle claims and another virtual table for the sum of medical claims.

The views will be:

```
CREATE VIEW vehicle_claim AS
SELECT empid, SUM(c_amount) AS 'total vehicle claim'
FROM claim
WHERE c_type IN('Motorcycle', 'Car')
GROUP BY empid;

CREATE VIEW medical_claim AS
SELECT empid, SUM(c_amount) AS 'total medical claim'
FROM claim
WHERE c_type = 'Medical'
GROUP BY empid;
```

With the select statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM user u LEFT JOIN vehicle_claim v on u.empid = v.empid
    LEFT JOIN medical_claim m ON u.empid = m.empid
```

In this query, I am selecting ALL users and I `LEFT JOIN` my two views. I do this so you will get data even if a user does not have any (vehical/medical)claim.

[Working SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c8ba7/5/0)

Comment: how to select table view more than 2? which mean that, i would like to display one more view table in select statement.For example "others claim".

Comment: thank you very much @simon, i am understand n able to do it right now.

Comment: there is one problem. the table cant display user_id on the first column of the table.

Comment: while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    print "<tr>";
    
     print "<td>" . $row['empid']. "</td>";
     print '<td><a href="claim_info.php?id=' . $row['empid'].'">'. $row['userName'].'</a></td>';
     print "<td>" . $row['mileage claim']. "</td>";
     print "<td>" . $row['medical claim']. "</td>";
     print "<td>" . $row['parking claim']. "</td>";
     print "<td>" . $row['other claim']. "</td>";
    print "</tr>";}

Comment: @parkchu try to print every row and see what's in it: while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { print_r($row); }

Comment: this the output after follow what you asked :

Comment: Array ( [0] => 2 [empid] => [1] => ilham [fname] => ilham [2] => hanafiah [lname] => hanafiah [3] => admin@gmail.com [email] => admin@gmail.com [4] => ilham [userName] => ilham [5] => 7ef6156c32f427d713144f67e2ef14d2 [p_Word] => 7ef6156c32f427d713144f67e2ef14d2 [6] =>  [rp_Word] => 7ef6156c32f427d713144f67e2ef14d2 [7] => 014-8764312 [phone] => 014-8764312 [8] => Kelana Jaya [onsite] => Kelana Jaya [9] => 2 [10] => 20.40 [mileage claim] => 20.40 [11] => 2 [12] => 50.00 [medical claim] => 50.00 [13] => 2 [14] => 20.00 [parking claim] => 20.00 [15] => [16] => [other claim] => )

Comment: @parkchu you are currently getting a lot of duplicate data, this is probably because you are doing a SELECT *. I would suggest only selecting the data you need. If you have trouble doing this, I would suggest starting a new question and showing the query that you are doing, the database structure, your code and the output.

Comment: if we look at the array above, duplication happened only on empid, because, it take all the empid from 4 views(mileage,medical,parking,other) i have created. it cant show empid because i dont mentioned from where the empid should be display.

Comment: solved now. instead of select * , i just called selected entity to display. i dont know how to explain the answer. thank you @simon and others.

Comment: "select u.empid, u.userName, m.mclaim, d.dclaim, p.pclaim, o.oclaim from user u, m_claim m, d_claim d,p_claim p,o_claim o where u.empid=m.empid AND u.empid=d.empid AND u.empid=p.empid AND u.empid=o.empid";